# Cannot Find 'play' command in terminal

Tags: audio-playback

I am trying to add sound effects to live audio on a Raspberry Pi.
I can succesfully do the same in terminal on my Mac using the following command.

```
play "|rec -d overdrive 30 tremolo 50 50”
```

However when I enter 'play' in terminal I receive the following error:

```
-bash: play: command not found
```

I cannot add the same effects using 'aplay'.

Whilst searching for a solution I came across this video in which the guy is doing exactly what I want using the play command, but from within a script?

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_kS7CnM5Ns0
Does this mean you cannot enter it directly in the terminal?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

So, I did a bit more research and found that 'play' is only available when sox is installed on the Pi.
So I installed Sox using the following command:

```
sudo apt-get install sox
```

Then I tried the same command that failed before, which I believe should play whatever is being received through the mic:

```
play "|rec -d overdrive 30 tremolo 50 50”
```

Again this failed (can't remember the error).

Not sure why but I removed the first part of the command:

```
play "|
```

And entered only the following:

```
rec -d overdrive 30 tremolo 50 50
```

Which worked and I could speak into the mic and the sound would play out of the speakers with the applied effects.

I have no idea why this works because I would have thought that the command:

```
rec
```

Without specifying a file name to save the recording to, would fail?

Comment: Both your question and answer use wrong typographical quotes which won't work in commands. Please make sure to copy&paste the commands you actually ran on your system.